# Convert EitherT[Future, A, B] to Option[B]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a method

```
def getInfoFromService(reqParams: Map[String, String]): Future[Either[CustomException, A]]
```

and I have another function

```
import cats.implicits._
def processInfoAndModelResponse(input: Future[Either[CustomException, A]]): Option[A] = {
    for {
         either <- input
         resultA <- either
     } yield resultA.some
}
```

So basically, I am trying to convert `Future[Either[CustomException, A]])` to `Option[A]`. The `resultA <- either` in above code would not work as map is not happy with type.

Comment: To convert EitherT[Future, A, B] to Option[B], you will have to block and which is not recommended

Answer (score 3):

What you try to do is basically something like

```
def convert[A](future: Future[Either[CustomException, A]]): Option[A] =
  Try(Await.result(future, timeout)).toEither.flatten.toOption
```

This:

- looses information about error, which prevents any debugging (though you could log after `.flatten`)
- blocks async operation which kills any benefit of using `Future` in the first place

Comment: thanks ,if I am not converting, this is one way of getting the actual value A 
```
future.flatMap{ case Right(value) => value case Left(e) =>}

```
Any other elegant way? appreciate

Comment: The elegant way is that if you start using async (Future/Cats's IO/Monix's Task), you keep on using it till `main`, so you never leave this async context.

Answer (score 2):

Monads do not work like that. Basically you can handle several monadic calculations with `for` for the same monad, but `Future` and `Either` are different monads.

Try

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def processInfoAndModelResponse(input: Future[Either[CustomException, A]]): Option[A] = {
  Await.result(input, 1.minute).toOption
}
```

**@MateuszKubuszok**'s answer is different in that it doesn't throw.

Comment: thanks ,if I am not converting, this is one way of getting the actual value A ``` future.flatMap{ case Right(value) => value case Left(e) =>} ``` Any other elegant way? appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You can't sensibly convert a `Future[Either[CustomException, A]]` to `Option[A]`, as you don't know what the result will be until the Future has completed.

`Future[Either[CustomException, A]]` might just bet kept that way, or put in IO as `IO[Either[CustomException, A]]`. If you don't care about `CustomException`, you can also capture it `Future` (or `IO`) error handling mechanisms, or just discard it entirely.

Some options:

absorb the CustomException in Future's error handling:

```scala
val fa: Future[A] = fut.transform(_.map(_.toTry))
```

ignore the CustomException an make the Future return with None

```scala
val fa: Future[Option[A]] = fut.map(_.toOption)
```

if you *really* want to block a thread and wait for the result,

```scala
Await.result(input, Duration.Inf).toOption
```

but all the caveats of awaiting apply. See [the documentaion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/concurrent/Await$.html#result%5BT%5D(awaitable:scala.concurrent.Awaitable%5BT%5D,atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):T), reproduced here:

> WARNING: It is strongly discouraged to supply lengthy timeouts since the progress of the calling thread will be suspended—blocked—until either the Awaitable has a result or the timeout expires.